# Jump over like this example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my attempt http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hKzfl on what i am trying to do. 
I want to make one ball on the circle that is constant in position i.e., not spinning. 
The main aim is to escape constant ball from the main ball. If the main ball which is rotating from my fiddle touches any of the constant ball then it should end. 
One point for each ball escape. I cant position a constant ball on the circle.

Here is an example of what i like to do: http://www.lessmilk.com/9/

```
<div class="circle">
  <div class="ball_blue"></div>
  <div class="ball_red"></div>
  <div class="ball_green"></div>
  <div class="ball_violet"></div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
      translate(-150px)
      rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
      translate(-150px) 
      rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.circle {
  border:1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin:25px auto;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.ball_blue {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size: 100px;
  animation: rot 3s infinite linear;
}

.ball_red {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.ball_green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:green;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: 65px;
}


.ball_violet {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background:violet;
  border-radius:50%;
  /* INITIALLY CENTERED */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  /* PUSH TO CIRCLE */
  transform: translate(-150px);
  /* PUSH OUT OF CIRCLE */
  margin-left: 215px;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far...you don't seem to have any animation or hover or jS/JQ listed?

Comment: @urbz - just try to help starters in programing and instead stop finding small mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving the blue ball according to its center (*with the `translate` in the animation*) so you need to take into account the radius of the ball to put it outside the circle..

```
@keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
               translate(-170px); /*from -150px*/
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-360deg)
               translate(-170px); /*from -150px*/
  }
}
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/Lcbgt

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i know i can move the ball with the translate in animation. my doubt is how can i make the other balls jump from the blue ball like this http://www.lessmilk.com/games/9/. in the given link if we press space bar the rabbits will jump from enemy. in the same way i want to apply to the balls and thats what i need...